# Can't connect to server after switching to HTTPS

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

so i switched to HTTPS, everything worked nicely exept the sockets.

If I try to visit website with the HTTP, the sockets connect, but if I try to connect with HTTPS I get:

The Error on Console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

Frontend:

```
function connect()
{
    if (!SOCKET)
    {
        var hash = getCookie('hash');
        if (hash == "") {
            //$.notify('You must login!', 'success');
        }
        if (hash != "") {
            $.notify('Connecting...', 'success');
        }
        SOCKET = io(':3001');
        SOCKET.on('connect', function(msg) {
            if (hash != "") {
                //$.notify('Connected!', 'success');
            }
            SOCKET.emit('hash', {
                hash: hash
            });
            $('#games tr').remove();
        });
        SOCKET.on('connect_error', function(msg) {
            $.notify('Connection lost!', 'success');
        });
        SOCKET.on('message', function(msg) {
            onMessage(msg);
        });

        SOCKET.on('disconnect', function(m) {
            SOCKET.emit('disconnect', {
                uhash: hash
            });
        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Error: connection already exists.");
    }
}
```

Node.js/Backend

```
var httpsOptions = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync("/path/to/cert/cert.pem"),
  ca: fs.readFileSync("/path/to/cert/chain.pem"),
  key: fs.readFileSync("/path/to/cert/privkey.pem"),
}

var server = require('https').createServer(httpsOptions);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(3001);
```

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: Socket is not connecting..

Comment: AKA i get Connection lost!

Comment: I'm not an expert on HTTPS certificates, but would those actually be able to apply to port 3001? I don't think that would work.

Comment: I imagine the port 3001 is internal, and accessed by Apache. I highly recommend using Apache for HTTPS instead of Node.

Comment: @rubenwardy yes but if node.js will be in HTTP, will it still connect to the server?

Comment: yes, as Apache will make it HTTPS. To the client, it's as if the Node app is HTTPS. So the client to Apache is HTTPS, it only communicates with HTTP internally.

Comment: Btw the HTTPS already works fine, exept the Socket.IO is not connecting.

Comment: Try `io('https://example.com:3001/');` instead of `io(':3001');`

Comment: then neither http, neither https works :D

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Comment: I'd try accessing it using an http client such as postman or curl, just to check that your can connect remotely

Answer (score 0):

Your Node application should only accept HTTP connections. Your Apache server should be responsible for the HTTPS. This simplifies your app, and allows Apache to load balance for you if you ever decide to do so.

So between your app and Apache should be HTTP, and then HTTPS between Apache and the client. There are many guides on how to do this, I suggest reading the [official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html)

If you decide to go against this, and implement SSL at the web app level (not recommended), then we'll need more information.

Comment: So the node.js server can stay in HTTP with the http.createserver?

Comment: Yes, you should bind the Node server to 127.0.0.1 so it's only accessible internally, and then get Apache to proxy connections on to it. So Apache will receive HTTPS connections, and then pass on the data to Node over HTTP. This is fine in terms of security as it's an internal communication.

Comment: Btw the HTTPS already works fine, exept the Socket.IO is not connecting.

Comment: Oh, right. Can you interact with it using a program such as Postman?

Comment: It should be able to, because the Node.js server is not giving any erorrs. I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with the front-side  js.